# Converting created document result to POCO

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have the following code that calls DocumentDB and creates a new Employee document. How do I then convert the result to Employee document again? Basically, I want to capture the created document and convert it to Employee object.

```
var result = await client.CreateDocumentAsync(collection.SelfLink, employee);

if(result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created)
{
   Employee emp = result.Resource; // How do I convert the result to Employee object here?
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Copying over Andrew Davis's answer, from the [DocumentDB MSDN forums](http://goo.gl/LOlQXZ), for the stackoverflow community)

The simplest way would be to have your Employee class inherit from Document, and then cast result.Resource to Employee.  If you don't want to inherit from Document, you could also define an explicit cast between Document and Employee.

Having the Employee class inherit from Document should work out-of-the-box if the names of the members of your Employee class match the names of the corresponding properties of the JSON representation.

Defining your own type conversion gives you more control, and might look something like this:

```
public static explicit operator Employee(Document doc)
{
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp.Name = doc.GetPropertyValue<string>("employeeName");
    emp.Number = doc.GetPropertyValue<int>("employeeNumber");
    /* and so on, for all the properties of Employee */
    return emp;
}
```

This would define an explicit cast from Document to Employee.  You'll have to make sure the GetPropertyValue strings (and type arguments) match your JSON properties.

Comment: Yup! He answered my question there. I appreciate your bringing the answer to this forum too.

Comment: This might work when calling CreateDocumentAsync as you have already created an Employee instance. But if you want to also be able to call ReadDocumentAsync to return 1 object then you can't cast _that_ back to Employee. For this you have to dynamic cast like Arnab's answer, or serialize the returned Resource document.

Comment: Beware inheriting Document, here is a console app you can use to observe strange behavior like duplicate properties being serialized as you make changes to your POCO: https://gist.github.com/Jacob-McKay/cd44a7339a329d763728348f43917db0 the comments in the Gist show what the output is, it's bad news bears!

Answer (score 48):

You can do a dynamic cast like this:

`Employee emp = (dynamic)result.Resource;`

Comment: Thanks for this tip!

Comment: That's fantastic! I can't seem to find documentation on what that actually does - as far as I can tell, (dynamic) should simply disable type checking, not perform magic like this. Also, it means I have no idea how to reproduce it in F#. Ideas?

Comment: @Lamarth Not sure why it works. Also, haven't worked on F#, so cannot say. Feel free to update the answer if you do figure it out :)

Comment: note that result.Resource won't throw any exception if some properties don't 
 match with Employee class.

Answer (score 8):

I wrote an extension method to do this:

```
public static async Task<T> ReadAsAsync<T>(this Document d)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms))
    {
        d.SaveTo(ms);
        ms.Position = 0;
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like

```
Document d;
var myObj = await d.ReadAsAsync<MyObject>();
```

Comment: This is the only working solution (aside from writing a huge `GetPropertyValue...` method) when it comes to the CosmosDbTrigger in Azure Functions 2.0. The trigger only works with a generic `IReadOnlyList<Document> input`, so you must do the conversion yourself. Thanks!

Comment: Addendum: if anyone experiences the same issue with the CosmosDbTrigger, please share your experience here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/issues/389 and perhaps it'll be resolved sooner

Comment: this is far better than using getpropertyvalue

Answer (score 1):

Here's a a synchronous extension method that doesn't silently miss properties like the `(dynamic)` cast method can. Uses recent .NET Core features Span and System.Text.Json for performance.

**Usage:**

```
Document doc; // source Document
MyType converted = doc.ConvertTo<MyType>();
```

**Implementation:**

```
public static T ConvertTo<T>(this Document item)
{
    using var stream = new MemoryStream();
    item.SaveTo(stream);
    var bytes = new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(stream.GetBuffer()).Slice(0, (int)stream.Length);
    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(bytes);
}
```