# Convert returned document from DocumentDB to C# class with strict type checking

Tags: c#, generics, serialization, azure-cosmosdb

`TEntity` is Generic BaseClass, and there are two classes derived from BaseClass `LocationEntity` and `ZoneEntity`.

Below `GetById()` has the context of `LocationEntity` but `response.Resource` is returning the object of `ZoneEntity`.

```
      public async Task<TEntity> GetById(string id)
    {
        TEntity readObj = null;
        try
        {
            var response = await client.ReadDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(dbName, collectionName, id),
                requestOptions);
            readObj = (TEntity) (dynamic) response.Resource; // it's ignoring the properties which does not match with TEntity (LocationEntity)
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return readObj;
    }
```

How to perform the strict type checking while converting DocuementDB `Document` to `TEntity`?

I want to throw exception or something when `response.Resource` is not of type `LocationEntity`.

Comment: `ReadDocumentAsync` returns a `ResourceResponse<Document>`. I assume your classes inherit from `Document`? If so, why aren't you using a generic constraint on `TEntity`? Either way, that `dynamic` cast looks out of place. Can't you use an `is TEntity` or `as TEntity` construction instead? Also note that `throw ex;` does not preserve the stack trace of an exception - `throw;` does.

Comment: I'm not inheriting from Document.. never felt the need. readObj =  response.Resource as TEntity is giving null. Thanks for info on ex.

Comment: Then what kind of document is `ReadDocumentAsync` returning, and how would you normally convert that to a `LocationEntity`? Just adding a cast to `dynamic` and then to your target type isn't magically going to work...

Comment: @PieterWitvoet It's happening. the class which is calling this class (GetById) is passing LocationEntity.

Comment: I understand that you're calling it as `GetById<LocationEntity>(...)`, but what I'm asking is: how would you normally (without generics) convert a `Document` to a `LocationEntity`?

Comment: see 2nd answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27118998/converting-created-document-result-to-poco I'm doing like this LocationEntity location = await _unitOfWork.LocationRepository.GetById(locationId.ToString());

Comment: Oh, ok. So `Document` implements `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`, which is how casting to `dynamic` allows it do convert to any type you want it to. I can't find much on how that conversion is supposed to work, but it's apparently quite forgiving when it comes to missing or non-matching fields. Unless there's a way to control that behavior you'll probably have to write your own code to check if the document actually contains all fields required by the target type.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up decorating some unique properties of `LocationEntity` with `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]` and same for `ZoneEntity` properties.
Now `readObj = (TEntity) (dynamic) response.Resource;` throws error if the property is not there.

This is one way I figured out but still hoping for some better way.